# trouble in install mod_ssl

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, mod-ssl

I make some trouble in install mod_ssl on my centos5.5.

when I type: `yum install mod_ssl`

Some wrong happened for:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
addons                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
update                                                   | 1.9 kB     00:00
http://www.jsonlitka.com/media/EL5/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: utterramblings. Please verify its path and try again
```

I tried to clean caches,

```
yum clean packages
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
0 package files removed
```

Then install again, still return the same error. I use `apache 2.2.3`, how to solve the problem? many thanks.

```
rpm -qa|grep httpd
httpd-2.2.3-45.el5.centos.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid repository named `utterramblings` which is preventing yum from working.

Disable or remove the repository (most likely from `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory) and then try again.

Comment: thanks, I removed it and works, need I move this file back if I finish install `mod_ssl`?

Comment: Don't bother, it's obviously broken. That guy's domain seems to have expired so he's probably not coming back.